# Is there a way to implement a delegate in a Base class for an inheritance model

Tags: c#

I am currently working in a Physical units class, in order to be able to track and convert units and perform some calculations without thinking if the value is in the correct unit.

My base class contains a delegate signature:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Delegate signature definition to keep track of convervions
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="toSelectedType"></param>
 public delegate void ConvertUnitsDelegate(object toSelectedTypeOrUnit);
```

The instance from the above delegate is created in the concret class

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Definition of the Static delegate to perform unit changes
 /// </summary>
 public static ConvertUnitsDelegate ConvertAllDistancesMethod;
```

my current problem is that if some of my colleagues wannts to implement their own Unit concrete class
they would have to see in my implementation and check that i have an instance from this delegate.

So i would like to ask if there is a possibility to define the delegate signature in an interface, that would enforce to inherit from base class and as well as from the interface.

So if anyone can help would be appretiated.

Regards!

---

I have an abstract class called UnitBase

```
 public abstract class UnitBase<DerivedClass> where DerivedClass : UnitBase<DerivedClass>, new()
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Delegate signature definition to keep track of convervions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toSelectedType"></param>
    public delegate void ConvertUnitsDelegate(object toSelectedTypeOrUnit);
```

}

This is a base class for my concrete class "Distance":

```
 public class Distance:UnitBase<Distance>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Definition of the Static delegate to perform unit changes
    /// </summary>
    public static ConvertUnitsDelegate ConvertAllDistancesMethod;
}
```

In class distance i declare an instance of the delegate, this approach is working, but i would like to define something extra like this:

```
     public class Distance:UnitBase<Distance>,IAdditionalInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Definition of the Static delegate to perform unit changes
    /// </summary>
    public static ConvertUnitsDelegate ConvertAllDistancesMethod;
}
```

This would enforce that if someone wants to inherit from by abstract base class is oblyed to declare an instance of the previous mentioned delagate signature.

Thank you for your question

Comment: `If some of my colleagues wannts to implement their own Unit concrete class they would have to see in my implementation and check that i have an instance from this delegate` - why, and what does that mean?

Comment: i mean they would have to see an implementation of how i use the base class in one concrete class, i would like to have an intuitive base class

Comment: Are you sure you need a delegate?  Why can't you just create an abstract method in UnitBase that returns void and takes an object as the argument?  Wouldn't that force any devs that implement UnitBase to write their method?  I'm poking to see what your goal for this delegate is, because it's not so clear.

Comment: @SeanSkelly my approach with the delegate is to trigger a function (In this case a function called ConvertTo) in every Instance of my derived class

Comment: @DonMiguelSan But that seems exactly what having an abstract method in your abstract base class will do for you.  If you define `public abstract void ConvertTo(object toSelectedTypeOrUnit);` in UnitBase, then every derived class must implement this.  (Also, you probably should not use `object` but maybe an Enum to represent the unit type you want to convert to.)

Comment: @SeanSkelly i have an abstract method but if i do not implement the delagte, the method will only be triggered in the instance where the void method was called, in the other hand if i declare the static delegate pointing to the `ConvertTo` Method, the method will be called in every existing instance of the class and not only in the instace where the void method was called

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the method will be called in every existing instance of the class".  Do you want all derived classes to register with some static object, such that all instances will have their version of the Convert method executed?  That sounds like a _list_ of delegates, or in other words an `event`.  Maybe we need more code added to the Question above, such as this ConvertTo function you talk about (but I see no code for).  How are you planning to call these Convert methods from other code?

Comment: @SeanSkelly Exactly! i am using a multicast delegate to perform that conversion. With a simple event i can call my `Distance.ConvertAllDistancesMethod`and every instance of Distance that are registered to my multicast delegate will execute the  `ConverTo()` method. Anyway my question was not related to analyze if the aproach will work or not, my question was more focused about how i can implement this delegate in an interface or inside the abstract class. Thank you! i appreciate your comments

Comment: Understood, but my comments are more aimed at why this question should be answered.  :)  Maybe there is a simpler way to solve what you are trying to solve.  Sometimes the best answer to "how do I accomplish _A_" is "don't do _A_; do _B_ instead".